# php excluding everything before a space

Tags: php

i have

> 9:42 say: 1 <+tk->sherlockholmes:
>   there was scream : why

I want to ignore everything before the first space(" ").

One method which i thought of was using the `explode()` function but i am having problem i did this :

```
$f_a = explode(" ",$tobesplit));
for ($i=1;$i<=count($f_a);$i++)
{
$ff_a .= $f_a[$i];
}
echo $ff_a
```

But it is giving errors can anyone tell why ?

And if there is a better way of doing this Please tell me

Thanks

Comment: $f_a = explode(" ",$tobesplit)); has one ) too many.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use [**`strpos`** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [**`substr`** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$part = substr($str, strpos($str, ' '));
```

Comment: If it has more than one more occurings of " " then what will it return ?

Comment: @kritya: It returns everything after (and including) the first space. From the documentation: *strpos — Find position of first occurrence of a string*

Comment: Or anyother way of contacting u

Comment: @downvoter: Please leave a comment, so that I can improve/correct my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `strstr()` function to get only the portion of the string after the first space, like this:

```
$portion = strstr($str, ' ');
```

For more information, take a look at [the documentation for the strstr() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/^[^ ]+ /', '', $tobesplit, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

$i is getting greater than the upper bound of your array. Change

```
for ($i=1;$i<=count($f_a);$i++)
```

with

```
for ($i=1;$i<count($f_a);$i++)
```

This and [Glass Robot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484509/php-excluding-everything-before-a-space/6484532#6484532).

Comment: Or better yet, use the `foreach($f_a as $element_of_f_a)` structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra close parenthesis on explode.

The is no need for the loop you can limit the number of results form explode:

```
list(,$result) = explode(" ",$tobesplit, 2);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors:

1. There is a closed parenthesis that you have to leave from first line.
2. You have to use "<" and not "<=" in for condition.
3. You have to declare ff_a out of cycle
4. You have to end with ";" last line.